# scanf not reading input properly in c

Tags: c, output

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,b;
    float f;
    scanf("%2d%3d%4f",&a,&b,&f);
    printf("%d %d %f",a,b,f);
    return 0;
}
```

The program ouput when I give input .(dot only):

```
.
0 1 0.000000
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Is there any logic behind the output?

Comment: No, unlike in some languages, the values of your variables 'a', 'b' and 'f' could have any value as you did not initialize them.  And the `scanf()` will only save as many values as match the input (in the case of '.' that's none of them).  BTW, scanf returns how many matches it found.

Comment: The output could just as well be "elephant". There could be no output whatsoever. The code could reach out and kick you in the shin. The world could end. All of these are permissible results of the code executing, as far as C cares.

Comment: ^^^ The C standard says once you invoke an "undefined behavior" that *ANY* result is possible, including world-ending elephants with bad haircuts, however some results are more likely than others.  In this case, printing whatever "leftover" value happened to be in the memory location the compiler picked out for your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `scanf` cannot extract 3 numbers when parsing, the respective variables remain unchanged, i.e. uninitialised in your case.
Accessing uninitialised variables yields undefined behaviour, which might be some indeterministic output, but could theoretically be also no output at all.

So there are two things in your code: first, initialise variables; second, check the return value of `scanf`, which stands for the number of items that have been successfully read and assigned:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    float f=0.0;
    int nrOfItemsRead = scanf("%2d%3d%4f",&a,&b,&f);
    if (nrOfItemsRead == 3) {
      printf("%d %d %f",a,b,f);
    }
    else {
      printf("wrong input.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input/Output:

```
12 34 12.5
12 34 12.500000

.
wrong input.
```